# What is wrong with passing options to the ChartJS object? Why does this not work?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So, I am working with a tutorial on ChartJS, and I can create a line chart fine, but when I hover on the points, it doesn't show data. And when I try to add a title, with the options array, it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
var buyerData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
            strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
            pointColor : "#fff",
            pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
            data : [203,156,99,251,305,247]
        }
    ]
  } 

  var options = {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Test'
    },
    responsive: true,
    animation: true });
  var buyers = document.getElementById('buyers').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData, options);
```

Comment: `animation: true });` --> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: Fixing that doesn't fix the problem for me. Still unresponsive and not animated